# IN operator for non prime attributes

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

Can I use the IN operator for non-primary key attributes in Cassandra? Or any other methods to  alternative instead of using IN in the query?

```
SELECT * FROM abc WHERE domain IN ('domain1','domain2') allow filtering;

 Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="IN predicates on non-primary-key columns (domain) is not yet supported"
```

Comment: No, you cannot.  Can you edit your question to include your table definition?  The better option would be to build a new table to support `domain` as a partition key.

Comment: Also, if you build your tables following a query-based design (recommended for Cassandra) you should *never* need to use the `ALLOW FILTERING` directive.

Comment: @Aaron, Thank you for your valuable comment. Also, can you recommend any alternative for IN operator in cassandra for my purpose.?

Answer (score 0):

> can you recommend any alternative for IN operator in cassandra for my purpose?

Remember, it is still possible to use the `IN` operator on a partition key.  It wouldn't say it's *recommended*, but it should be fine with a small number of parameters.  First though, you'd have to rebuild your table, or build a new table to support that query.

As I don't know your exact table definition, I'm going make some assumptions (like `abc_id`).

If you recreated your table similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE abc_by_domain (
  domain TEXT,
  abc_id TEXT,
  value TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (domain,abc_id));
```

Now write some data to it, and then this works:

```
SELECT * FROM abc_by_domain  WHERE domain IN ('domain1','domain2');

 domain  | abc_id | value
---------+--------+---------
 domain1 |      1 | 1st row
 domain2 |      2 | 2nd row

(2 rows)
```

Notes:

- I assumed a current, single primary key of `abc_id`.  Essentially, I made that a clustering key to ensure that the underlying rows now partitioned by domain would still be unique.  In your case, take whatever key column enforces uniquness in the `abc` table, and use that as a clustering key to accomplish the same thing.
- As per my warning above, this is known as a "multi-key query" which is an anti-pattern in Cassandra.  The problem, is that Cassandra cannot guarantee that data on two partitions will be on the same node, so it essentially picks a coordinator and runs two queries behind the scenes.  For two parameters, it's probably not too bad.  But I would try to keep that in single digits.

Comment: (code=2200 [Invalid query] message="IN restrictions are not supported on indexed columns") ,This error are generated when a prime attribute put in 'IN' condition (There are many prime attributes). Why this error comes in Cassandra?, What is indexed columns in Cassandra?